# Problem in reshaping numpy array of large size

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array with following dimensions :

(1611216, 2)

I tried reshaping it to (804, 2004)

using :

```
df = np.reshape(df, (804, 2004))
```

but it gives an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/Seismic/Geophysical/99_Personal/Abhishake/RMS_Machine_learning/RMS_data_analysis.py", line 19, in <module>
    df = np.reshape(df, (804, 2004))
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 232, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3222432 into shape (804,2004)
```

df = np.reshape(df, (804, 2004))

but it gives an error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/Seismic/Geophysical/99_Personal/Abhishake/RMS_Machine_learning/RMS_data_analysis.py", line 19, in 
    df = np.reshape(df, (804, 2004))
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 232, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3222432 into shape (804,2004)

Comment: 1611216*2=3222432. 804*2004=1611216. What do you expect to happen to the other 1611216 elements?

Comment: Thanks   user2357112 , I changed the initial dimension to (1611216, 1) it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reshape (1611216, 2) numpy array into (804, 2004).

It is because 1611216 x 2 =  3,222,432 and 804 x 2004 = 1,611,216. The difference in size of the two array is very large. I think you have to come up with another set of dimensions for your numpy array and that would depend on how you want to use your array.

Hint : (1608, 2004) will be a valid reshape.